# WP8 Parse handling toast notification when app is not running

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com service to push notification for my WP8 app. The problem is I cannot find a way to handle toast notification when my app is not running (unable to extract data from notification). Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Assuming you're not trying to use tile notifications this might work for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221550.aspx

Comment: I only use toast notification. I have checked the link but my app is not running, how can I receive the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to handle toast notifications on Windows Phone when the app is not running.